How to unset message in order pay page in woocommerce?
in the checkout/order-pay page in woocommerce, there is this message "You are paying for a guest order. Please continue with payment only if you recognize this order."
Do you know what function i should use to unset that (and dont show it)?
Thanks
Im not sure what function i should use in functions php file

navigate to this file:
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php
You will need access to your hosting, via FTP, SFTP, SSH, SCP...
open the file with a text editor,
comment adding "//" at the beggining of this lines:
            // Add notice if logged in customer is trying to pay for guest order.
            // if ( ! $order->get_user_id() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // If order has does not have same billing email then current logged in user then show warning.
            //  if ( $order->get_billing_email() !== wp_get_current_user()->user_email ) {
            //      wc_print_notice( __( 'You are paying for a guest order. Please continue with payment only if you recognize this order.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            //  }
            // }

save it, then refresh website, no more alert.
